# How to create a simple layout like a TextBlock with background and opacity?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

[image]

As the picture describles, the text length may change according to data returned from server. So the gray background can strech along with text length.

On the other hand, the background has opacity.
If I use:

```
<Border Background="Gray" Opacity="0.6">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind name}"/>
</Border>
```

This result the TextBlock also has a opacity.

If I use

```
<Border Background="Gray" Opacity="0.6"/>
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind name}"/>
```

This result if the text length is very long, the background border does not adjust it's length.

This will be used in a `GridView` template, so keep it as clean as possible.

So anyone has ideas? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a color resource with transparency:

```xml
<SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" Opacity="0.6" x:Key="GrayOpacityColor"/>
```

**Usage**

```xml
<Border Background="{StaticResource GrayOpacityColor}">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind name}"/>
</Border>
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks bro, this the the best solution.